# Why does plt.imshow flip coordinates compared to plt.scatter?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, coordinates

The coordinate axis directions seem to be inverted between array indices and plots. Does someone have a satisfactory answer as to why matplotlib likes to display images inverted?

Code that demonstrates my question:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.zeros((10, 10))
img[2, 4] = 1

plt.imshow(img)
plt.scatter(2, 4)
```

The output image will show a white pixel and a dot at positiones mirrored at the image diagonal.

[image]

This effect caused a lot of confusion for me (and others I have talked to) and I was wondering if there is a sensible explanation for it. To me, it seems that matplotlib interprets the first axis of a numpy array as the y-coordinate and the second as x. As this is not aligned with the mathematical x-y right hand notation this is confusing.

Comment: `scatter` uses the usual graphing convention, `imshow` uses image/picture conventions.  Did you pay attention to the `origin` parameter of `imshow`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question. To answer it shortly this is not a problem of plt.imshow but different views for origin of Cartesian coordinate system in conventional mathematics. In a matrix, the origin of Cartesian coordinate system is upper left corner by convention which makes x axis to **visually** be considered as *vertical axis* incrementing downwards (notice your plot's reversed vertical axis) and y axis as *horizontal axis* incrementing to the right. While on Cartesian coordinate systems with normal view, the origin is at the middle forming normal horizontal x axis and vertical y axis.

In pixel processing you are dealing with memory mapping which uses a similar concept as in matrices and this can make an illusion by which you may think plt.imshow has transposed your data in the process. You can easily solve this problem by transposing your image back to the normal view similar to below (inverting y axis is optional):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.zeros((10, 10))
img[2, 4] = 1

plt.imshow(img.transpose())
plt.gca().invert_yaxis() # optional
plt.scatter(2, 4)
```

[image]

It is funny that if early mathematicians would have chosen lower left corner as origin of matrix, similar to Cartesian coordinate systems with normal view, this difference would not have been created!